# VBA Piovot table - Selecting multiple report filter

Tags: vba, pivot-table, xls

I am very new to VBA and also to this group, please bear with me if i am asking silly queries. 
I am trying to write VBA programming pivot table to know how many members are claimed to the project.

I will be getting account ID which will be present in report filter which can be one or many like Account ID `"AI124", "AI245", "AI456", "AI671"` from 100 of account ID (from 50K records)

1) I am not able to filter  for multiple  Account ID's using VBA.

2) Team members would had claimed on this account ID from last year, but i need to populate from 11th of March where value will be specified in the header

I tried to check in internet and started writing below code which may not be correct but providing as reference.

```
Sub CreatePivot()
    ' Creates a PivotTable report from the table on Sheet1
    ' by using the PivotTableWizard method with the PivotFields
    ' method to specify the fields in the PivotTable.
    Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField

    ' Select the sheet and first cell of the table that contains the data.
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DATA").Select
    Range("A1").Select

    ' Create the PivotTable object based on the Employee data on Sheet1.
     Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard
    ' Specify row and column fields.
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Emp Last Name")
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField
    objField.Position = 1

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Emp Ser Num")
    objField.Orientation = xlRowField
    objField.Position = 2

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Week Ending Date")
    objField.Orientation = xlColumnField
    objField.Position = 1
    ' Specify a data field with its summary
    ' function and format.

    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Total Hrs Expended")
    objField.Orientation = xlDataField
    objField.Function = xlSum
    objField.NumberFormat = "#,##0"

    ' Specify a page field.
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Account Id")
    objField.Orientation = xlPageField

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   'ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").ManualUpdate = True
   objTable.ManualUpdate = True
   'objTable.PivotFields("Account Id").ClearAllFilters
   ' objTable.PivotFields("Account Id").CurrentPage = Array("PJ1234", _ "AI82159", "AI5444")


    '-------------
    Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("Account Id")
    objField.Orientation = xlPageField
    Myarray = Array("PJ1234", "AI5444", "AI82159")
    For x = 1 To objField.PivotFields.Count
        objField.PivotFields(x).Visible = False
    Next
    For x = 0 To 3
        objField.PivotFields(Myarray(x)).Visible = True
    Next
   objTable.ManualUpdate = False

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True



    ' Preview the new PivotTable report.
    ActiveSheet.PrintPreview

    ' Prompt the user whether to delete the PivotTable.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If MsgBox("Delete the PivotTable?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        ActiveSheet.Delete
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
 End Sub
```

your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You haven't really asked a question. Have you tried your code? Did it generate errors? What did you expect to happen and what parts didn't work as expected?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: Hello OldUgly, Thank you. My question is how to write VBA program to select multiple Account ID's as part of report filter? also added my code for reference. thanks in advance.Also there were no error and when tried to include in Myarray I am only getting first Account ID details not getting for multiple account ID's

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested any of the comments in this answer.

---

Minor thing - probably not contributing to your problem ...

Is the Pivot Table really on Sheet1? Regardless, I would recommend modifying this ...

```
Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard
```

... to something like this ...

```
Set objTable = Worksheet("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1")
```

You can find the PivotTable name on the Analyze Ribbon.

---

It looks as though you are using `PivotFields` where you should be using `PivotItems`. I would change this ...

```
objField.PivotFields(x).Visible = False
```

... to this ..

```
objField.PivotItems(x).Visible = False
```

... and change this ...

```
objField.PivotFields(Myarray(x)).Visible = True
```

... to this ...

```
objField.PivotItems(Myarray(x)).Visible = True
```